# Is {$↔,⊕$} complete set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I feel they are not but i am not able to prove that they are not functionally complete.
It is possible that equation represented by using the two connectives in question can be true or false .

Is my assumption that they are not complete correct ? How to prove it ?

Comment: Does $\oplus$ mean XOR?

Comment: @Arthur Yes you are right

Comment: @Arthur How to prove that set is incomplete ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that they are not complete, because they are both affine transformations. 
Any combination of these functions will always return a truth table that is symmetric, and therefore will not 'cover' all the non-symmetric functions.

Comment: How to write proof for it . It is intuitive explanation.

Comment: Suppose you have a set of connectives $A$. Then for any $P,Q$, and we have the property: for any $\circ \in A$, $P \circ Q = \neg P \circ \neg Q$, then for any $\circ_1,\circ_2 \in A$ any combination of these two also has the same property.